# Android conditional Operator issue

Tags: android, if-statement

I am in the process of making an app that outputs a number between 1 and 9000 that the user selects this number is then stored as a variable that the user can call on later.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String number = urNum.getText().toString();
    if (number >= " " && <= 9000) {

        numOut.setText("Your number is set to: " + number);
    }
}
```

This code: (number >= " " && <= 9000)
has errors in it stating that: The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) String, int
-How do I go about fixing these errors?

Help on this matter would be wonderful!

Comment: Just as an advice : learn Java before Android to understand the basic syntax of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, that is not valid Java syntax. You have to specify the variable each time. Second, you can't compare a number to an empty string, you have to first convert it to an integer, then compare it to another integer.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String numberString = urNum.getText().toString().trim();
    int number = Integer.valueOf(numberString);
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 9000) {
        numOut.setText("Your number is set to: " + number);
    }
}
```

If there is a chance the value entered is not a number, you need to handle that, too:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String numberString = urNum.getText().toString();
    int number;
    try {
        number = Integer.valueOf(numberString);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        number = 0;
    }
    if (number >= 1 && number <= 9000) {
        numOut.setText("Your number is set to: " + number);
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: You may want to educate yourself on [`try/catch` blocks](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_try_catch_block.shtml), as well as [Android `EditText` digit restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919360/how-do-i-restrict-my-edittext-input-to-numerical-possibly-decimal-and-signed-i), and lastly [`if` statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) with [multiple conditionals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253030/best-way-to-format-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your number is currently a string, convert it to an int, then you can do something like:

```
int number = Integer.valueOf(urNum.getText().toString());
if (number >= 0 && number <= 9000)
```