# How to make nested IF statements neater

Tags: python, if-statement

This question could be asked in a language independent way but I'm asking in the context of python since different languages will have different nuances.

I recognize that this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253030/best-way-to-format-if-statement-with-multiple-conditions) but I think mine is different in that I'm asking about a case where putting the two conditions in the same if statement with `&` will generate an error.

Let's say I want to see if `abc[x]` is equal to 'fish' but let's say I don't know for sure that `len(abc)` is >= to x.  I can't just have `if abc[x]=='fish'` because it might be index out of range.  As such I need to do

```
if len(abc)>x:
    if abc[x]=='fish':
        dostuff
    else:
        dootherstuff
else:
    dootherstuff
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this where I don't have two else statements that end up doing the same `dootherstuff`?  If I want to change what `dootherstuff` is later than I have to change it in both places but by then I might forget.  Sure I could try to comment the code to remind myself later or make `dootherstuff` a function but that still seems second best.  A lot of times when I wind up doing this the `dootherstuff` is just a one line of code so making it a function doesn't feel much better even though it addresses the subsequent change scenario.

Comment: What about a try-except? Generally faster too, if length will be within bounds most of the time.

Comment: [`and`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) is a short-circuit operator in Python - it sounds ideal for your purpose.  Alternate suggestion: try "if all()": `if all([condition1, condition2])`

Comment: wrapping around try-except just replaces the outer if-else and I still end up do `dootherstuff` twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, here it is:

```
if len(abc) > x and abc[x] == 'fish':
    dostuff
else:
    dootherstuff
```

`and` short-circuits, so `abc[x] == 'fish'` will only be evaluated if `len(abc) > x` is `True`. Most languages have a similar operator (e.g. `&&` in C).

`&` is for bitwise "and," and doesn't short-circuit, so don't use that.

Comment: @kindall, if `x` happens to be exactly `len(abc)`, wouldn't this still cause an  index out of range exception when `abc[x] == 'fish'` is checked, since `len(abc) >= x` evaluates to true?

Comment: Yeah, but it's the same problem as the original.

Comment: I didn't realize this worked.  I know that doesn't work in VBA but I guess it's my fault for assuming VBA's faults onto other languages.

Comment: @Alejandro good point, I'm used to R where lists and vectors start at 1 instead of 0.  It's a simple fix to change the `>=` to just `>` though

Comment: @DeanMacGregor: Yeah, assuming any other language works like VBA is gonna send you off into the weeds. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could definitely combine both conditions with a logical `and` operator. Most, if not all, modern programming languages employ [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), including Python. I.e., the process the expression step by step, and do not evaluate parts of it they do not need. Here, if the left side of an `and` expression is `False`, the whole thing will be `False`, and there's no need to evaluate the righthand side, so, something like this would be completely safe:

```
if len(abc)>=x and abc[x]=='fish':
    dostuff
else:
    dootherstuff
```