# Good practices in nested If conditions

Tags: javascript, java, if-statement

Which of the below is a good practice.
Second looks more readable for me but would like to know how others think.

Solution 1 :

```
case colorElementEnum.ICON:
        color = colors.buttonText;
        if (isHighContrast) {
          if (!titleColor) {
            if (disabled) {
              color = colors.lightGray;
            }
          }
        }
        return color;
```

Solution 2 :

```
case colorElementEnum.ICON:
        color = colors.buttonText;
        if (isHighContrast && !titleColor && disabled) {
              color = colors.lightGray;
        }
        return color;
```

Comment: *" ... but would like to know how others think"* - What I think is that you are experienced enough to have (and trust) your own opinions on style and code readability :-).  But as someone who has been using StackOverflow for some time, you should have realized by now that opinion-based questions are clearly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the latter option, because as it is said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/253049/9391162), it is neat and readable, even if you have long names for variables, you can make it shorter and cleaner as so:

```
bool aa = FirstVeryLongConditionMethod(a) && SecondVeryLongConditionMethod(a);
bool bb = FirstVeryLongConditionMethod(b) && SecondVeryLongConditionMethod(b);
bool cc = FirstVeryLongConditionMethod(c) && SecondVeryLongConditionMethod(c);

if( aa && bb && cc)
{
   //This is again neat & readable
   //although you probably need to sanity check your method names ;)
}
```

Unless you have a certain functionality for your else condition, you can use above. As an another idea, you can use a specific function for checking your complicated checking (if you get). Thanks to @Torbjørn and @eoin-campbell, you can also find another ideas in that link.